# How to convert tuple with multiple elements into string

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, converters

I have a list of tuples that looks something like this:

```
list = [('spam', 9), ('the', 7), ('in', 6), ('my', 6), ('by', 5), ('and', 4)]
```

I want to turn each tuple into a string.  I have some code that doesn't quite work...

```
for tup in list:
    tup = str(tup)
    print(tup)
```

and I'm a little lost.  The code above just prints the same list I started with.  Could someone help me out please?  I'm new to python and programming in general so I'm sorry if this is a noob question.

Comment: What exactly do you want/expect? The default string representation of a tuple looks much like the python code that would create it.

Comment: `print(tup)` does the exact same thing as `str(tup)` and `repr(tup)`. What output do you expect instead?

Comment: You shouldn't use variables like `list` that are the names of built-ins - you may get unexpected behavior later!

Comment: As a side note, this looks like data you'd want to store in a `dict` (or maybe a `collections.Counter`) rather than a list of tuples. It doesn't really affect _this_ question (except that you'd need to add a `.items()` before the colon), but the rest of your code might well get a lot easier with that change.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing exactly what you claim to want: turning each tuple into a string.

The problem is that the default string representation (in fact, both the human-friendly `str` and the programmer-friendly `repr`) looks exactly like the source code: converting `('spam', 9)` to a string gives you the string `"('spam', 9)"`.

If you want something different, you can do it. But you have to decide what you want before you can write the code for it. Then it's just a matter of using string formatting, or concatenation, or `join`.

For example, let's say you want it to print out this:

```
spam: 9
the: 7
in: 6
…
```

Then you can do this:

```
for tup in list:
    tup = '{}: {}'.format(*tup)
    print(tup)
```

Or, if you want this:

```
You have 9 copies of "spam".
You have 7 copies of "the".
…
```

Then it's this:

```
for tup in list:
    tup = 'You have {1} copies of "{0}"'.format(*tup)
    print(tup)
```

And so on.

Comment: Another possibility: only print *one* element from the tuple (probably the string value).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: or maybe print `spam` 9 times, then `the` 7 times, etc.?

Comment: Lots of possibilities at this point... even printing the strings in [1] numerical order, like "and by my in the spam"... heheh...

Comment: @abarnert: Exactly. Loads of options, and no word from the OP as to what is expected. I've VtCed as 'unclear what you are asking'.

Comment: @Roberto: No, obviously you're supposed to print the numbers as strings in order of the adler32 of the string encoded as EBCDIC. :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
for tup in my_list:
    tup = ' '.join(map(str,tup))
    print(tup)
```

Edit - just explaining a little bit:
`' '.join(...)` - this is the string `.join` method, it needs a joining string (`' '` here) and an iterable as argument. The iterable contains strings.
`map(str,tup)` - the `map()` function takes a function name (in this case `str`) and an iterable, and applies the function to all members of the iterable. So it will make the tuple into a list of strings, ready for the `.join` method to work on. It is equivalent to the list comprehension `[str(i) for i in tup]`.
So you could also do `tup = ' '.join(str(i) for i in tup)`

Comment: I doubt `spam9` is the output he wants either… but maybe this is enough to show him that he has to _decide_ what he wants before anyone can write the code that gives it to him…

Comment: I put a space as string, at least now it's `spam 9`! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [str.join()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join together the elements of each tuple. It would then require you to iterate over the contents of list and put each element into the str.join() function.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively an one-liner. (Just as complement to the more elaborate answers!):

```
>>> '; '.join(map(lambda tpl: '%s: %s' % tpl, list))
'spam: 9; the: 7; in: 6; my: 6; by: 5; and: 4'
```

Taking Martijn Pieters comment into account:

```
>>> ' '.join(map(lambda tpl: '%s' % tpl[0], list))
'spam the in my by and'
```

Comment: I think that will be treated as unambiguous by both 2.x and 3.x, but really, but it's not ambiguous to a human reader! Just using a better name than `i` that makes it clear that each element is a tuple might be sufficient, but I might put either the lambda body or the whole lambda in parens…

Comment: @abarnert: roger that! ;-)